# How to create a collection of all products that have attribute ABC?

Tags: collection, product-list

How to create a collection of all products that have attribute ABC?
Can someone please guide me as i am new to Magento?

Then I would like to link that collection to a custom static block using href link?
Please provide me step by step approach as i am a newbie.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `eq`:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->
    addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' => 'code', 'eq' => 'ABC')
                ));
```

You can find lot of ways in future on [THIS POST](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

Comment: You can place this code wherever you are getting the colection